# Same difference in alternate rows per sub group

Tags: r, dplyr, row, difference, alternate

I have data frame where i need to find difference but for every alternate row the difference should stay same as the things to do are same like this:

[image]

but I have used this:

```
things <- data.frame( category = c("A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B"),
                      things2do = c("ball","ball","bat","bat","hockey","hockey","volley ball","volley ball","foos ball","foos ball"),
                      number = c(12,5,4,1,0,2,2,0,0,2))


    things %>% 
      mutate(diff = number - lead(number,order_by=things2do))
```

but it is not helpful,as I am getting this:
[image]

Can i get some help here?

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks. Just edited as per guidelines.

Comment: Just for this sample data, you could do: `group_by(things, things2do) %>%
mutate(difference = diff(number))`.

Comment: @jazzuro that does not work, as your method gives difference between consecutive numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

things2 <- things %>%
  spread(category, number) %>%
  mutate(diff = B - A) %>%
  gather(category, number, A:B) %>%
  select(category, things2do, number, diff) %>%
  arrange(things2do)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to group the data by `things2do` and subsequently take an iterated difference.

```
library(dplyr)
things %>% 
  group_by(things2do) %>%
  mutate(diff = diff(number))
```